# Streaming from HDFS folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to implement a `scala` + `spark` solution to streaming a word count information from new values from a HDFS folder, like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import StreamingContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

object HdfsWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: HdfsWordCount <directory>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HdfsWordCount")
    // Create the context
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    // Create the FileInputDStream on the directory and use the
    // stream to count words in new files created
    val lines = ssc.textFileStream(args(0))
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I tried with `spark-shell` running `HdfsWordCount.main(Array('hdfs:///user/cloudera/sparkStreaming/'))`
 and it just give a `|` and leaving me to type. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Interesting way to run your class in spark. Have you tried spark-submit?

Comment: You’re using single quotes around your input directory, which is not how you define a string literal in scala. Try changing to double quotes.